# How to install mpeg4 and h264 in ubuntu offline?

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, video-player, gstreamer

I am not connected with the internet .  So I need to download mpeg4 plugin and h264 plugin for playing videos . Please comment a line for downloading? I am new to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

For offline installing, you can just download .deb files and then install them via this command :

```
sudo dpkg -i YOURPACKAGE.deb
```

And I guess that the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and the `ffmpeg` packages are enough for playing mpeg4 and h264 codecs. So you can download them from this launchpad link and Ubunutu package link :

[download ubuntu-restricted-extras package from here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-restricted-extras)

(You should choose package depends on your operating system version and architecture for example I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 64bit , So I'm choosing `ubuntu-restricted-extras_65_amd64.deb` from `The Zesty Zapus` tab.)

[download ffmpeg packages from here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ffmpeg)

And then you can install them with this commands (if .deb file has been downloaded to Downloads folder):

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i ubuntu-restricted-extras_65_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ffmpeg_packages.deb
```

(Also ffmpeg's depends must be installed.)